# Trying to inherit parent permissions but setfacl doesn't work as intended

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS and I've installed `acl` using `sudo apt-get install acl`.

I'm trying to create a `www` folder under `/srv` that the web server has read/write access to in addition to my user account. I want all future folders and files created under `/srv/www` to inherit permissions, user, and group.

Here is my progress:

`cd /srv`

`sudo mkdir www`

`sudo chown -R ryan:www-data www/`

`sudo chmod -R a-rwx www/`

`sudo chmod -R ug+rwX www/`

`sudo setfacl -Rdm u:ryan:rwX,g:www-data:rwX www/`

`getfacl www/`

Output:

```
# file: www/
# owner: ryan
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:ryan:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Problem is, whenever I create a new file or folder in `www/` the permissions are inherited but not the owner or group. How do I get the owner and group to inherit? I thought specifying a user or group between the colons :[user or group]: would cause them to be inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a user/group between the colons means that those permissions apply to that user/group. So, for example, you can have a folder mode 0600 but readable by some random user via a `user:user:randomuser:rwx` ACL.

You can `chmod g+s /srv/www` to make files/folders inherit its group. You cannot inherit the user on Linux (on some systems `chmod u+s /srv/www` would do that) . Usually you have no need to, as you can use ACLs to grant any permissions to any users/groups you want.